# How to skip redundant line in DateTimePicker?

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I'm using .NET's [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) in a dropdown UITypeEditor to show in a property grid. The DateTimePicker shows a redundant line  that means you have to click twice to show the useful calendar bit. How can I hide it so it skips straight to the calendar?

[image]

Backstory: Previously used used MonthCalendar, which doesn't have the redundant line. However, MonthCalendar crops itself sporadically (when edit one date in the grid, then another), which looks bad.

[image]

Comment: This looks like what you are looking for: [Datetimepicker in a property grid](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6ad79ce8-4c42-4300-a31f-afeaded61525/datetimepicker-in-a-property-grid)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is any (easy) way to remove this part because is what defines the `DateTimePicker` as opposed to `MonthCalendar`.

What you call "useful calendar bit" is actually a `MonthCalendar`, why don't you rely on this control instead?

Or if you don't want to rely on `MonthCalendar`, perhaps you should consider a custom DateTimePicker: lots of codes in internet ([sample1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38972/Nullable-datetime-column-in-NET-DataGrid-with-Date), [sample2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13613/A-date-control-better-than-DateTimePicker)); even creating one by your own (after getting some inspiration from the available ones). Anything before considering the option of modifying a so important part of the control.

Comment: We were using MonthCalendar before, but it behaves very badly—gets cropped sporadically (will share a screenshot). DateTimePicker behaves better.

Comment: I have used MonthCalendar quite a few times and haven't ever had any problem (unless you want to resize it).

Comment: And what about a custom DateTimePicker (I have updated my answer)?